# Rails - How to exclude blocks of code from fragment cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm using fragment cache but i have inline code that is user specific like:

```
<% cache @page do %>
  stuff here
<% if current_user %>
  user specific
<% end %>
  more here
<% end %>
```

So i want to exclude the several blocks of code that are user specific. Is there a way to do that in Rails or should i make an if statement in the beginning and make different caches for logged users and regular visitors? (i will have major duplication of code this way).

Comment: Use your helpers and then you can just call the method then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For per-user fragments, you can put models in array an array:

```
<% cache [@page, current_user] do %>
```

Rails will make a cache-key out of them, like:

```
pages/page_id-page_timestamp/users/user_id-user_timestamp
```

This way your fragments will be invalidated on a user/page update since the time-stamps are coming from their `updated_at` (see [cache_key](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Integration.html#method-i-cache_key) for details).

Comment: hey @jdoe this is great for private information the user holds but i'm looking for, say showing an "edit this" link if the user is logged or not. Maybe i'll just load it afterwards in javascript at the end

Comment: @Tom You can replace `current_user` with `!!current_user`. This way the cache-key will be ending with `/true` (if user is logged) and `/false` otherwise.